# Visual Studio Oracle Connection working for one project but not for other

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, oracle

I am connecting to oracle db from my c# applications.The problem is I am able to connect to DB from one application but I am unable to connect from the other one even though I am using the same DLL.

The application iam able to connect is a Console application
And the one I am unable to connect is a web application.

I am using the same code in both the applications to connect.
The error that is being thrown in the web application project is as follows

```
 **TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified**
```

I am on a windows 7 OS.The web application ,i am having problem with,is copied from a windows xp machine.

The console application ,which is working,is created on the current machine

Any thoughts on why the error is being occurred?

Answer (score 0):

Search for oracle home directory and then there is a folder (network) then folder (admin).
there is file called tnsnames.ora.

It should look like ($ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora )

Referance [TNS format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007)

Comment: it is working for one application...but not for the other..how can you explain that